# Why am I having an ambiguous type error when calling a WebMethod on ASP.NET Web Application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, debugging, web-applications

The message sent to browser is as follows:

> The type My.API.Class is ambiguous: it could come from assembly '[on Temporary ASP.NET Files]' or from assembly '[on bin folder]'

The problem occurs when debugging a Web App, specifically when making a request to a WebMethod of a WebService.

The project compiles just right. It generates My.Website.dll on bin folder and if I publish the Web Application. It works fine.

The asmx file is on the root of the application. The CodeBehind file is on App_Code and its marked to be compiled to generate My.Website.dll.

I should be missing something really important.

I found someone having the same issue with a possible related cause. [Check it out](http://www.csharp411.com/web-service-ambiguous-type-question/). The way this person exposes its problem is somehow similar but I get starting to be lost when he talks about a proxy class and shared dlls I don't use.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), the App_Code folder should be used only on Web Site projects. That's the reason the CodeBehind of the asmx was compiled at runtime too.

The initial question was made based on a Web App. But I didn't specify this Web App. was been manually changed from a Web Site project.

To solve my problem I did the following:

1. Convert the project to Web Application. This will make App_Code to be renamed to Old_App_Code.
2. Moved all the Old_App_Code resources to a Class Library and then referenced this library into the Web Application.

@Tony: Thank you for guiding me.

Comment: I upgraded an old VS2005 web service to VS2010. In VS2005, I had an App_Code folder. So I ended up with this problem in VS2010. Moving the code files to the root solved this problem for me. thanks.

Comment: and how do you move these Old_App_Code resources to a class library when they are @helpers (in my case I stored them in a Utils.cshtml)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to debug issues like this is to use the "Modules" window in the Debug->windows menu of Visual Studio.  It will show you all loaded assemblies.  In particular, you want to look for My.API.Class in the modules list more than once.  Sort the list by order loaded, and look at the dll right before it (that's usually the one responsible for the assembly to be loaded).  The most likely cause of this is that one of your references also references My.API assembly, but references a different version of the assembly than your site does.

Comment: My.API assembly is on My.Website.dll. I've changed the error message of the problem to point the 'Temporary ASP.NET files' folder as the location of one of the assemblies referencing My.API.Class. Does this change the problem in any way? I can't see how your proposal for debugging the problem is helping.

Comment: Yes, that's much different. A dll in temp asp.net files means it was automatically generated by compiling your website code.  I'd try deleting the contents of that folder, and see if that clears it up.  If that doesn't work, you need to find out why you are getting both an assembly in your bin directory, and one in your asp.net temp files directory.  I'd start by using Ildasm or a reflection tool to look at each assembly and look at the contents.

Comment: I did delete all the temp files and folders. Then tried to use ildasm and realized the two assemblies had compiled almost the same references. That way I got to the solution to my problem.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helped me discover that a second assembly that had been included from the client was being simultaneously loaded and causing an ambiguous reference (turns out the assemblies were identical but named differently depending on where they are supposed to live.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by adding your assembly name at the end of the attribute "Class" ex :

Instead of

```
<%@ WebService  Language="C#" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/WebService.cs"  Class="WebService" %>
```

Use

```
<%@ WebService  Language="C#"  Class="WebService, YourProjectName" %>
```

When you're making a web site, the assembly name is something random starting with "App_Code" but when you change it to a Web App the assembly name will be "YourProjectName".

This problem is only on development environment, so I guess my solution is better because you won't have to rename your folder (thie could cause problem with your source control).