# How to resolve typename not found in ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, iis, typename

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET 4.0 for a company intranet. The application began as a Web Site application and I used IIS 7.5 to 'convert to application'. This moved a class module to a folder named Old_App_Code and when I now try to run the application, it can not find the TypeName that I have referenced in an ObjectDataSource parameter. My question is "How should I resolve the problem?". Is it ok to try to reference the code in the Old_App_Code folder, or is there another way of doing this. My code is in vb, not that it makes much difference. My IDE is Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

Answer (score 0):

App_Code should be the main folder which should have all your logical code.

Check this

[Why am I having an ambiguous type error when calling a WebMethod on ASP.NET Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171257/why-am-i-having-an-ambiguous-type-error-when-calling-a-webmethod-on-asp-net-web)